# Find value within a range in database table

Tags: mysql

I need the SQL equivalent of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899129/find-value-within-a-range-in-lookup-table).

I have a table like this

```
ID MN MX
-- -- --
A  0  3
B  4  6
C  7  9
```

Given a number, say 5, I want to find the ID of the row where MN and MX contain that number, in this case that would be B.

Obviously,

```
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ? BETWEEN MN AND MX
```

would do, but I have 9 million rows and I want this to run as fast as possible.  In particular, I know that there can *be* only one matching row, I now that the MN-MX ranges cover the space completely, and so on.  With all these constraints on the possible answers, there should be some optimizations I can make.  Shouldn't there be?

All I have so far is indexing MN and using the following

```
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ? BETWEEN MN AND MX ORDER BY MN LIMIT 1
```

but that is weak.

Comment: Well, you could change `? BETWEEN MN AND MX` to `MN >= ?`, or else drop the `ORDER BY MN LIMIT 1` (obviously not both, though). But . . . what's "weak" about your current query? Without knowing what you dislike about it, it's hard to know what alternatives to suggest.

Comment: What are the current query times? BETWEEN is pretty fast. Did you run an `explain` on your query to see the breakdown of how MySQL will execute the query?

Comment: @MikePurcell - I haven't done it yet.  I was just wondering if there was collective wisdom on how to do things like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an index spanning MN and MX it should be pretty fast, even with 9M rows.

```
alter table T add index mn_mx (mn, mx);
```

**Edit**

I just tried a test w/ a 1M row table

```
mysql> select count(*) from T;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1000001 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.17 sec)

mysql> show create table T\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: T
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `T` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mn` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mx` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mn_mx` (`mn`,`mx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1048561 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from T order by rand() limit 1;
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id     | mn        | mx        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 112940 | 948004986 | 948004989 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.65 sec)

mysql> explain select id from T where 948004987 between mn and mx;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T     | range | mn_mx         | mn_mx | 5       | NULL | 239000 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from T where 948004987 between mn and mx;
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| 112938 |
| 112939 |
| 112940 |
| 112941 |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

In my example I just had an incrementing range of mn values and then set mx to +3 that so that's why I got more than 1, but should apply the same to you.

**Edit 2**

Reworking your query will definitely be better

```
mysql> explain select id from T where mn<=947892055 and mx>=947892055;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T     | range | mn_mx         | mn_mx | 5       | NULL |    9 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

It's worth noting even though the first `explain` reported *many* more rows to be scanned I had enough innodb buffer pool set to keep the entire thing in RAM after creating it; so it was still pretty fast.

Comment: Strangely, I did *not* get that same drop-off in rows scanned when replacing the `between`.  In fact, even the index doesn't seem to actually speed it up much (between 0.06 and 0.15 seconds).  The table ended up being much smaller than I was anticipating and I think it's just all in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no gaps in your set, a simple gte comparison will work:

```
SELECT ID FROM T WHERE ? >= MN ORDER BY MN ASC LIMIT 1
```